# Background image is not display in print preview

Tags: css

I am Using laravel 5.4, but not display in print preview.
What to do..?

```
.bg {
  @media print {
    visibility: visible;
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("../logo/back_id_card.JPG");
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}
```

Comment: if any answer is not working for you then please add `!important` after your css rules like `background-image: url("../logo/back_id_card.JPG") !important;` and preview it, it'll work definitely.

Answer (score 10):

Please try this to see if the problem persists(applies to all elements*):

```
@media print {
    * {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
}
```

The -webkit-print-color-adjust property is a non-standard CSS extension that can be used to force printing of background colors and images in browsers based on the WebKit engine.

Comment: works in chrome but not in firefox

Comment: @Vahid2015, yes the webkit is for chrome you can add for firefox -moz-...

Answer (score 1):

***I think your code is wrong:***

*This should be:*

```
.bg {
  @media print {
    visibility: visible;
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("../logo/back_id_card.JPG");
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}
```

***Like this:***

```
@media print {
 .bg {
    visibility: visible;
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("../logo/back_id_card.JPG");
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}
```

> `.bg` should be inside the `@media print` not the other way around.

hope this was helpful for you.